# g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1plus) - where do I start?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

I am porting code that compiled on **Ubuntu 14.04** to **16.04**. I have cloned my git repo, installed dependencies and tried the usual `make` command, soon I hit a `g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1plus)` ... yet I am not sure where to start to diagnose and resolve this issue.

I will share as much as I can, see if someone can guide me through a resolution.

#### Ubuntu

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

#### g++

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

#### python

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

#### Some environment variables

```
PYTHON       /usr/bin/python2.7
ARCH         x86_64
OS           Linux
VERSION      4.4.071generic
PLATFORM     linux2
HOSTNAME     deploy
USER         myUser
WUSS_BUILD   NO
CCVER        gcc
PYLIBDIR     build.x86_64-linux2
LIBDIR       build.x86_64-linux2
BINDIR       build.x86_64-linux2
ODIR         build.x86_64-linux2-gcc
STATICLIBDIR build-static.x86_64-linux2
```

#### Error

The `make` command leads to

```
+++ Compile mycore/boost_json.cc to build.x86_64-linux2-gcc
g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1plus)   <===
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
mk/makelib2.inc:48: recipe for target 'build.x86_64-linux2-gcc/mycore/boost_json.o' failed
make[1]: *** [build.x86_64-linux2-gcc/mycore/boost_json.o] Error 4
Makefile:152: recipe for target 'make.stage1c' failed
make: *** [make.stage1c] Error 2
```

The error message seems to be pointing at a `g++` compiler error (?)

`makelib2.inc:48`

```
$(ODIR)/%.o : %.c
        @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        @echo "+++ Compile $< to $(ODIR)"
        @$(CC) -MMD -MP -MF $(@:.o=.d) -c -I$(ODIR) $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_$*) -o $@ $<
```

I realize that this is going to be very difficult to craft a proper question that would lead to getting proper help. So please bear with me and feel free to suggest adding anything that may help. Unfortunately, I can't share the code.

## Update

Going to try upgrade `g++` to a more recent version. Following [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618474/how-to-install-the-latest-gcurrently-5-1-in-ubuntucurrently-14-04)

[HERE how to install **g++ 7** on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863517/how-do-i-install-g-7-on-ubuntu)

[HERE how to install **gcc 6** on Ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/application2000/73fd6f4bf1be6600a2cf9f56315a2d91)

Comment: We probably need to see what command-line was generated for `@$(CC) -MMD -MP -MF $(@:.o=.d) -c -I$(ODIR) $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_$*) -o $@ $<` when compiling the boost_json.o target.

Comment: Like the error message say, you should file a bug report to gcc (if there is not already one for the same bug). Internal compiler error are always bug in the compiler.

Comment: Report it here https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla 5.x is old though, you may want to install a newer version.

Comment: ha! I figured I was working with latest. on my Ubuntu 14.04 I was working with `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4`.

Comment: @n.m. do you know the right way to upgrade `g++` to its latest version. I think your suggestion may resolve my issue, please feel free to add it as answer.

Comment: Try to find a GCC version 6 at least. Since GCC 7 has been recently released.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/application2000/73fd6f4bf1be6600a2cf9f56315a2d91

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## How I resolved my `g++` segmentation fault issue

Inspired by [this thread](https://gist.github.com/application2000/73fd6f4bf1be6600a2cf9f56315a2d91)

I executed the following on my **Ubuntu 16.04**

```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential software-properties-common -y
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y 
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install gcc-snapshot -y
```

After what `g++` was incremented from `5.4.0` to `5.4.1` which resolve the segmentation fault issue

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04) 5.4.1 20160904
```

Comment: I know it's old, but this fixed the issue for me too. Cheers

Comment: This answer really saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Simply do as you were instructed:

> Please [submit a full bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla), with preprocessed source if appropriate.

Comment: right, I guess that's one thing, although that doesn't resolve my issue. What might resolve is installing (as suggested in the comments) a more recent version of the `g++` on Ubuntu 16.04 if that's supported, because this issue may have been resolved already right?

Comment: The people who receive your bug report will be best placed to help you triage it and find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't solve your problem using above methods, you can have a try to check if you are running out of disk space using below command. This is the workaround of my problem.

```
df -h
sudo du -h --max-depth=1
```