# I am trying to install lightly-qt with cmake but I get this error message:

Tags: cmake, zsh

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
The C compiler

```
"/usr/bin/cc"
```

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: /home/jamesc/Lightly/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_b349a/fast && /usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_b349a.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_b349a.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jamesc/Lightly/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_b349a.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_b349a.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /home/jamesc/Lightly/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
cc: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault signal terminated program cc1
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://bugs.archlinux.org/> for instructions.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_b349a.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_b349a.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 4
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jamesc/Lightly/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_b349a/fast] Error 2
```

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

Comment: Just follow the error message: "Please submit a full bug report". You could try apply different modifications to your system. E.g. try to update the compiler, like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44288591/3440745). Or try to downgrade the compiler (sometimes this helps). Not sure what kind of help you expect from us with such a little information.

Comment: Can you compile any C program? What is the output of like `/usr/bin/cc --version`?